# how do i pass program arguments in java for my Fitnesse Fixture?

Tags: java, fitnesse

I have a fixture that needs some System arguments to be passed into it.How can i do the same.
ie java MyClass -Darg1=x -Darg2=y

how do i pass the -Darg values into my test.

@Dan. My Bad that I mentioned command line arguments.What I really intend to do is pass System properties as you pointed out.I have some settings like Region(NA/EMEA etc),Environment(SIT/UAT) etc based on which various urls etc differ.I have to compose tests in Fitnesse where I pass the values for the test screen from my decision table.But I want to be in a position to dictate that these tests should be run on so and so region/env combination.AT present I have a junit Test that triggers Selenium playback and I have control over its invocation from IDE/Maven by passing -Dregion etc.With Fitnesse I want to know how to pass these System arguments so that my Fixture when it gets invoked has access to these properties and it triggers playback of Selenium accordingly.

Comment: Do you really mean command line arguments?  -D arguments are really JVM System Property arguments.  These are accessed through System.getProperty(name) rather than through the args in the main.

Even then, I think that you are confusing an aspect of implementation with intent.  What do you want show/test in your test?  Are you trying to show what would happen if your program was run with a specific set of arguments?

Answer (score 3):

To pass variables into FitNesse, you can set an environment variable. For example, start FitNesse from the command line like this:

```
set SUT=www.google.de
java -jar fitnesse.jar -p 8080
```

You can use environment variables in FitNesse like other variables - '${SUT}' in a FitNesse test table will be replaced with www.google.de in the above example.

Then to get the value of SUT into the test fixture, you can add a static class in the test fixture like this:

```
public class Environment {
    public static string SUT;
}
```

And somewhere in your FitNesse Setup code set the Environment SUT variable:

```
!|script|Environment|
|SUT|${SUT}|
```

Environment.SUT is then available throughout your Fixture code.

---

### Update:

Also see Dan's comment on how use Java System variables by starting fitNesse with the -D parameter.

Comment: You can also do this with -Dtarget.site=www.google.de.  

so: java -Dtarget.site=www.google.de -jar fitnesse.jar -p 8080

Then you can do the same thing with ${target.site}. Both java system properties and environment variables can be accessed using the ${varaiblename} syntax.

Comment: Thanks Dan - I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: I'm working in Java - not sure if the above was meant to be pseudocode, but I had to do: `public class Environment { public static String SUT; public Environment() { super(); } public void setSUT(String SUT) { Environment.SUT = SUT; } }` Then my Fitnesse setup code was: `!|script|Environment|` `|set SUT|${SUT}|`. Apologies for the awkward formatting inside a comment.