# Running a FitNesse script on all child pages

Tags: java, integration-testing, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I'm trying to use the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021071/how-do-i-pass-program-arguments-in-java-for-my-fitnesse-fixture) to make a system property available to Fixtures in my FitNesse suite (basically, use a script to set a static class property). It's working OK if I include the script in each test page, but these pages are maintained in Excel by users so I want to put the script section into a parent page and have every child include it - is this possible? The script section is pretty simple:

```
!|script|com.mycorp.fitnesse.ServerInterface|
|ServerPort|${fitnesse.server.port}|
```

This simply calls a method which sets a static variable within ServerInterface which is then used by Fixture code classes to make requests to a server.

Alternatively, any simpler way of getting a system property value into my Fixture code would be welcome (of course, the properties can't be accessed directly by System.getProperty() because the Fixtures are run in a different JVM to the Fitnesse server itself).

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple actually - just use one of the [Slim Special Pages](http://butunclebob.com/FitNesse.UserGuide.SpecialPages) such as SetUp to house the script.

Comment: I would suggest using SuiteSetUp, as the script only needs to be executed once for the entire suite, not for each test.